# Make a function returns some value instead of context

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a function like;

```
function a(){ return this;} a();
```

This will return something like[image]

I want to make this function returns some value say '10' for example. But I don't want to change anything in the function. Is it possible?

For returning a value we can do it like

```
function a(x){ return x;} a(10);
```

But I don't want to change my function like this.

Comment: function a(){ return 10;}

Comment: I don't want to remove "return this" from my function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a strange question, but you can call a function with whatever scope you want it to execute under. If you want the scope to be a Number, then so be it.

This should do what you want:

```
function a() { return this; }
a.call(10)
```

Comment: not in es5... in es5 a number object is returned not the primitive object that was passed... but in es6 it will work

Comment: Yes, you will get a Number Object. But that will behave like a regular primitive in most cases.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: @BKM I'm not really sure why you needed to do this, but you're welcome.

Comment: Actually it's not needed in my project. I got a doubt about how really it's gonna work. Anyway thanks for your quick reply

Answer (score 1):

@Jivings answer is great. I'm adding this only to add to the range of solutions.

```
function a() { return this; }

var num = Number;
num.prototype.a = a;

var ten = num(10);
ten.a();
```